# "Do not disturb" mode with caller profiles (e.g. switch favorites)

Tags: calls, system, android-14

I need the "Do not disturb" mode modificated with caller profiles (e.g. switching user definded favorite settings).
This to enable something like caller groups in single and mixed posibillities, e.g. family or job or special friends...
Is that implemented, codeable or needs to be a feature request to Google itself?

Comment: Not implemented //Coding questions are off topic here// Look for a custom ROM that has this feature or make a feature request to Google